# Displaying file size: 1000b = 1kb or 1024b = 1kb?

Tags: ios, file, size, byte

I am making a iOS app where the size of some files is diplayed in MB. My question is if it is correct to calculate 1000 byte = 1kb or 1024 byte = 1kb ? I have seen that Finder on the mac calculates with 1000b, but an iOS file manager called iFile calculates with 1024b. The wikipedia article didn't really answer my question. I am just askig speifically for file size not HD capacity etc.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD: http://xkcd.com/394/

Comment: @SLaks Hahah, I think this is the best answer to the question so far :P +1

Comment: It didn't help me to find an answer but it made me rofl :P

Comment: Bit of a late reply, but I'd always say 1024 based on binary seeing as though computers work in powers of two!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is if it is correct to calculate 1000 byte = 1kb or 1024
>   byte = 1kb ?

Both are correct, and both are used in different situations.

1024 is more common for file sizes, while 1000 is more common for physical disk sizes, but neither is always used that way. As you mentioned, some programs uses 1000 for file sizes, and for memory cards 1024 is often used rather than 1000.

An example of how inconsistently the units are used is the 1.44 MB floppy disk. It's neither 1.44 * 1000 * 1000 bytes nor 1.44 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, but actually 1.44 * 1000 * 1024 bytes.

An effort was made to introduce the kibibyte unit, which is always 1024 bytes. It never was a hit, but you can see it used sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

1024b = 1kb

This 1000b stuff is metric...  ;)

Answer (score 1):

The true unit of measurement for 1KB is 1024B: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kilobyte?q=kilobyte

However, some manufactures of software and hardware, in an effort to decieve consumers in order to make themselves look better, may calculate it as 1000B. This is actually a pretty recent trend.

Comment: Down voted because I general English language dictionary is not the place for technical explanations of words.

Answer (score 1):

basic units(Physic, math...) :

K = 10^3, 
M = 10^6

so...

1Km are 1000m.. but no 1km are 1024m

So...
A lot of programs using not good units 1024Kb  = 1Mb
Historical bug. :)

Windows using normal 1kb = 1024
But if you buy disc 1GB you buy 10^9 B

Comment: It's not quite a bug, more a historical ambiguity between the prefixes, and some sketchy salesmanship by hard drive vendors.

Answer (score 1):

[Kilo-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilo-) denotes multiplication by one thousand (not 1024). Modern terminology reflects this fact:

1. [1 kilobyte = 1000 bytes = 8000 bits](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#1kB)
2. [1 kibibyte = 1024 bytes = 8192 bits](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/#1KiB)

Previous use of **kilo** (with bytes) was based on the approximation that 2<sup>10</sup> (1024) is merely **close to** 1000.

Imagine being tasked with coming up with a word that means 1000 bytes after some "loose approximation" had already taken the most obvious term you'd want to use. This lead to the corrected meanings listed above.

This terminology has been standardized. The following is a quote from page 143 of the [The International System of Units](https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf/2d2b50bf-f2b4-9661-f402-5f9d66e4b507):

> The SI prefixes refer strictly to powers of 10. They should not be
> used to indicate powers of 2 (for example, one kilobit represents 1000
> bits and not 1024 bits). The names and symbols for prefixes to be used
> with powers of 2 are recommended as  follows:

- kibi Ki 2<sup>10</sup>
- mebi Mi 2<sup>20</sup>
- gibi Gi 2<sup>30</sup>
- tebi Ti 2<sup>40</sup>
- pebi Pi 2<sup>50</sup>
- exbi Ei 2<sup>60</sup>
- zebi Zi 2<sup>70</sup>
- yobi Yi 2<sup>80</sup>

The `bi` in the prefixes above are based on the word "binary". When you append "bit" or "byte" onto them, you get the units listed [here](http://www.lonniebest.com/DataUnitConverter/) (where conversions are also provided).